# How do I get the rendered ID to use globally as a variable to send an API request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

How do I get the rendered `<li>` class name `item.imdbID` or the key `item.imdbID` to use in another API request? The API needs the ID to search correctly but I am having trouble extracting this information to use globally on my onClick method `seasonsList()`. I'm extremely new to React and am still trying to wrap my head around the logic!

This is the code of my render method in React:

```
 render() { 
        if (this.state.screenType === 'init'){
            return (
                <div>
                  <input type="text" onChange={this.textInput}></input>
                  <button onClick={this.search}>search</button>
                  <div className="results">
                    {this.state.loading ? (
                      <div>search for a series</div>
                    ) : (
                      <div>
                        results:
                        <ul>
                            {seriesArrayTitles.map(item=> (
                                <li key={item.imdbID} className={item.imdbID} onClick={this.seasonsList}>{item.Title}</li> )
                            )}
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do. You can just provide this value as an argument to your `this.seasonsList` function.

```
seasonsList = (id) => {
    // doing something with the id
}

render() {
    if (this.state.screenType === 'init') {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.textInput}></input>
                <button onClick={this.search}>search</button>
                <div className="results">
                    {this.state.loading ? (
                        <div>search for a series</div>
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            results:
                            <ul>
                                {seriesArrayTitles.map((item) => (
                                    <li
                                        key={item.imdbID}
                                        className={item.imdbID}
                                        onClick={() => this.seasonsList(item.imdbID)}
                                    >
                                        {item.Title}
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```